# Altair data aggregation

Tags: python, charts, altair

I am trying to plot on Altair the following:
x = daily time stamp
y = count of records as the data is nominal not quantitative

when i try to aggregate x by month or quarters, is it possible to show y as the average count of records per day instead of the the sum?

```
chart = alt.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(
    x = alt.X('Date:T'),
    y = alt.Y('count(Name):Q'),
    color = alt.Color('descriptor:N')
)
chart
```

when i try to do

```
chart = alt.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(
    x = alt.X('month(Date):T'),
    y = alt.Y('count(Name):Q'),
    color = alt.Color('descriptor:N')
)
chart
```

it gets aggregated by total for the month, is it possible to do average of the count per month?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can apply multiple aggregates using Altair's [transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/index.html) syntax. For your chart, you might do something like this:

```
alt.Chart(data).transform_aggregate(
    daily_count = 'count(Name)',
    groupby=['Date', 'descriptor']
).mark_bar().encode(
    x = alt.X('month(Date):O'),
    y = alt.Y('mean(daily_count):Q'),
    color = alt.Color('descriptor:N')
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this Jake! I just started with Altair, quite intuitive.